# Extending an existing python macro from predicting 2 categories to 3 categories

Tags: python, image-classification

I need some help to get an existing python example which works nicely to classify 2 categories and extend it to classify 3 categories.
here's the working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2 as cv
from tqdm import tqdm
import random

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

DATADIR = "C:/D/tmp/CNN"
CATEGORIES = ["Cat1","Cat2"]
IMG_SIZE = 100
training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:  

        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  

        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):  
            try:
                img_array = cv.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
                new_array = cv.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize to normalize data size
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])  
            except Exception as e:  
                pass
            #except OSError as e:
            #    print("OSErrroBad img most likely", e, os.path.join(path,img))
            #except Exception as e:
            #    print("general exception", e, os.path.join(path,img))

create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))
random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
y = []
for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)


#print(X[0].reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1))

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y = np.array(y)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=16, epochs=20, validation_split=0.3)

model.save('cat1_2.model')
```

My idea was to, apart from creating the 3rd folder with the images of the 3rd category to:

1- change to `CATEGORIES = ["Cat1","Cat2","Cat3"]`

2- change `model.add(Dense(1))` to  `model.add(Dense(3))`

3- change `model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))` to `model.add(Activation('softmax'))`

4- change from `loss='binary_crossentropy'` to `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`

Unfortunately that, although the model seems to converge to a very good accuracy (above .95) it always predict

[[0. 0. 1.]]

regardless the input.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

solved....rookie mistake....the error was actually in the prediction calling. basically I was passing the image to the model without scaling 0<->1 (i.e. diving by 255)..Once I did that predictions started to make sense...